# fireworks font / text problem

Tags: fonts

Fireworks cs5 (and cs4 for that matter) does not display fonts correctly. What I mean by that, Text appears different in browsers then it appears in fireworks. Changing anti-aliasing mode does not correct the problem and custom aliasing simply is not something I am willing to adjust every single time.

Anyone knows a workaround or a fix for this?

---

EDIT:

This link summarizes my problem. http://blog.hipchat.com/2010/11/03/how-adobe-ruined-fireworks-cs4cs5/

Comment: (Flagging for possible move to [graphicdesign.se](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)) Be more specific. Fireworks is explicitly intended for web design and overall puts *more* effort into being close(r) to what your browsers render versus say, Photoshop. Ideally, screenshots will be involved, to show exactly what you're complaining about.

Comment: @Su' Please refer to the link I've provided in my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean about adjusting "custom aliasing", but browsers use subpixel AA for text; an image editing program can't do that since subpixel rendering is display-dependent and can't be hardcoded into a raster image.

Comment: I know no other software that does what fireworks does with text. In fact, this problem did not exist in version 3. (I have posted a link in my question to an article regarding this.)